# How do you do an unsigned/logical shift right on an Integer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, bit-shift

`shiftR` in Data.Bits does an arithmetic shift for `Integers`. Is there a standard way to do a logical shift right?

I can think of two round about ways to do this. Take the quotient by 2^n:

```
unsignedShiftR i n = i `quot` (2 ^ n)
```

Another way would be to mask the upper n bits after an arithmetic shift (although I'm not sure you can get the position for the mask).

Comment: What should be the result of shifting `-1` right by one bit? Infinity...?

Comment: @DanielWagner, the (virtual) 1 bits in a negative `Integer` extend infinitely off *to the left*. Sticking a 0 bit before all of them should leave the value the same, because it is never reached.

Comment: @dfeuer If that is indeed the spec, then just go ahead and use the arithmetic shift given by `shiftR`. Since jp.rider63 explicitly said `shiftR` doesn't do what he wants, though, I suspect that is not in fact the spec.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I don't understand what you're saying. `Data.Bits` always does its best to pretend that a negative `Integer` is actually represented as two's complement with infinitely many bits. `testBit (-1::Integer) (10000000::Int) ==> True`. There doesn't seem to be any sensible way to distinguish between an arithmetic and a logical shift in this context.

Comment: @dfeuer That's my point. He's asking how to do a logical shift instead of an arithmetic shift on `Integer`, and _that doesn't make sense_.

Comment: @DanielWagner, ah, so we are in agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason it's not included in `Data.Bits`, but there's a [GHC primop](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/GHC-Prim.html#g:3): `uncheckedIShiftRL#`. Also, [`GHC.Base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/GHC-Base.html) exports a safer version as `iShiftRL#`:

```
iShiftRL# :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#
a `iShiftRL#` b | isTrue# (b >=# WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS#) = 0#
                | otherwise                          = a `uncheckedIShiftRL#` b
```

We can wrap either the `GHC.Base` version or the primop with varying amounts of checking:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import GHC.Base
import GHC.Prim

uncheckedIShiftRL :: Int -> Int -> Int
uncheckedIShiftRL (I# n) (I# i) = I# (uncheckedIShiftRL# n i)

unsafeIShiftRL :: Int -> Int -> Int
unsafeIShiftRL (I# n) (I# i) = I# (iShiftRL# n i)

iShiftRL :: Int -> Int -> Int
iShiftRL (I# n) (I# i)
  | isTrue# (i >=# 0#) = I# (iShiftRL# n i)
  | otherwise = error "shift by negative amount"
```

Comment: This works for `Int`s, but what about `Integer`s? Also, where do you find the definitions for unboxed types?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that you asked for Integer specifically. GHC uses GMP, and [GMP has the function you want](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division.html#Integer-Division), but it's not included in the GHC bindings. You can alternatively use `quot` with exponents of 2 (because it rounds towards 0, instead of negative infinity as with `shiftR`).

Comment: It's too bad GHC doesn't include this. I can use `quot`, so I'll accept this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As far as `Int` goes, the standard way of doing it is converting it to an unsigned type and shifting it there:

```
import Data.Word

ushiftR :: Int -> Int -> Int
ushiftR n k = fromIntegral (fromIntegral n `shiftR` k :: Word)
```